# Bash script to pull pending Linux security updates from remote servers

Tags: linux, bash, nagios

I'm trying to pull pending linux updates from remote servers and plug them into Nagios. Here's a stripped down version of the code - the code that's giving me an error:

```
UPDATES=$(sshpass -p "password" StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server:/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)

echo $UPDATES
```

Error message:

> sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

Comment: "No such file or directory" should give you the hint that it can't find sshpass.  Use the full path or make sure this script is run with a complete PATH env variable.

Comment: This entire command is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command in the question is wrong in multiple ways.

```
sshpass -p"password" \
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server "/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check" 2>&1
```

For the `-p` option, there shouldn't be any space between the option and the value.

`sshpass` needs a command as argument, which is `ssh` in this case.

`StrictHostKeyChecking=no` should be following the option `-o` for `ssh`.

A space, not a `:` is needed between `user@server` and the command you are going to run remotely, i.e., `/usr/lib/....`

Comment: Done :) Didn't know that, thanks again. Btw, does the ssh session end on its own after the command is completed?